# using golang channels. GETTING "all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"

Tags: go, goroutine

iam currently playing around with go routines, channels and sync.WaitGroup. I know waitgroup is used to wait for all go routines to complete based on weather wg.Done()  has been called enough times to derement the value set in wg.Add(). 
i wrote a small bit of code to try to test this in golang playground. show below

```
var channel chan int
var wg sync.WaitGroup


func main() {

  channel := make(chan int)
  mynums := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} 
  wg.Add(1)

  go addStuff(mynums)
  wg.Wait()
  close(channel)
  recieveStuff(channel)
 }

 func addStuff(mynums []int) {

   for _, val := range mynums {
       channel <- val
   }
   wg.Done()
 }

 func recieveStuff(channel chan int) {
    for val := range channel{
    fmt.Println(val)
 }
}
```

Iam getting a deadlock error. iam trying to wait on the routing to return with wg.Wait()? then, close the channel. Afterwards, send the channel to the recievestuff method to output the values in the slice? but it doesnt work. Ive tried moving the close() method inside the go routine after the loop also as i thought i may of been trying to close on the wrong routine in main(). ive found this stuff relatively confusing so far coming from java and c#. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `wg.Wait()` wouldn't return until `wg.Done()` has been called once.

In `addStuff()`, you're writing values to a channel when there's no other goroutine to drain those values. Since the channel is unbuffered, the first call to `channel <- val` would block forever, resulting in a deadlock.

Moreover, the channel in `addStuff()` remains nil since you're creating a new variable binding inside main, instead of assigning to the package-level variable. Writing to a `nil` channel blocks forever:

`channel := make(chan int) //doesn't affect the package-level variable`

Here's a modified example that runs to completion by consuming all values from the channel:

https://play.golang.org/p/6gcyDWxov7

Comment: im not sure why the channel <- val will block forever? isnt it inside a goroutine?  when i called  go addStuff(mynums)?  i thought the for loop would run until all elements are added to the channel. Then , wg.Done() would execute. causing wg.Wait() to return?

Comment: The channel you're writing to is unbuffered and writing to an unbuffered channel blocks until another goroutine has received from that channel. You're calling `wg.Wait()`, which blocks until `wg.Done()` is called, so `receiveStuff()` never runs to drain the channel.

Comment: so draining the channel needs to happen instantaneously in an unbuffered channel?

Comment: @user1232726: You need concurrent send and receive on an unbuffered channel. That's the entire point of using an unbuffered channel, to communicate and synchronize concurrent processes -- [Communicating Sequential Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes)